# Почему зубно́й звук, а не зубный? И почему: перехо́дный и переходно́й, призывный и призывно́й?

Tags: орфоэпия, морфемика

Современный толковый словарь русского языка **Ефремовой:**

**Зубно́й.** II прил.
Образующийся при сближении передней части **языка** с верхними передними **зубами**; дентальный (о звуке).

Такой вопрос был задан на  **[mail.ru.](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/57679334)** Почему не говорят **"зУбный врач",** ведь в слове "зуб" ударение на единственной гласной "у".

**Ответы интересные**, например:

*Во всём есть смысл, выбор этого смысла, и возможность просмотреть применяющееся влияние тонкости речи... Не существует "правильно" или "неправильно", существует изменение смысла!*

Любопытно, **красивые** слова, но их **смысл** я так и не поняла.

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ**

В русском языке **много таких пар**: домОвый и домовОй, грунтОвый и грунтовОй, джИнсовый и джинсОвый, перехОдный и переходнОй, призЫвный и призывнОй.

А вот внятного ответа **от лингвистов** по этому поводу я так и не видела. Обычно объясняют, откуда **исторически** взялись эти пары. Но почему в современном языке существуют такие **СЕМАНТИЧЕСКИЕ** оттенки?

А как вы думаете?